# Need If for checking if AD users are in a String

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a string with all users of the domain, and another with folder permissions (Groups/Users).

I need help with the if statement in my code, it needs to know if any user of the domain is in the string of the Groups/Users that have access to the folder.

```
if ($allusers -like "DOMAIN\*") {
    $ws.Cells.Item($row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Write-Host "true"
} else {
    $ws.Cells.Item($row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 
    write-Host "false"
}
```

Example of strings:

Folder permissions:

```
DOMAIN\User1 Allow --  Modify, Synchronize
DOMAIN\---- Allow   --   ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
DOMAIN\---- Allow   --   Modify, Synchronize
DOMAIN\---- Allow   --   Modify, Synchronize
```

User list:

```
User1
User2
User3
```

The users come from:

```
$allusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=DOMAIN,dc=de" | select Samaccountname
```

And the permissions come from:

```
$OrdnerAccess = $Folder | Get-Acl | select AccessToString
```

They should both be lists if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: They're lists, but lists of custom objects, not lists of strings. You need to use `select -Expand <property>` to make them lists of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your source data are actually lists of strings, not lists of custom objects:

```
$allusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=example,dc=org" |
            Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName
$OrdnerAccess = Get-Acl $Folder |
                Select-Object -Expand AccessToString
```

Then you can build a regular expression from `$allusers`, like this:

```
$re = $allusers -join '|'
```

or like this, if there are special characters in the account names (which I wouldn't recommend):

```
$re = ($allusers | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
```

Then you can check `$OrdnerAccess` like this:

```
if ($OrdnerAccess -match $re) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Note, that the `AccessToString` property will give you a string representation of all access permissions of a folder as a single string. If you need to evaluate the permissions separately you need to split that string:

```
$OrdnerAccess.Split("`n")
```

Comment: It gives me the error. "[Selected.System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity] does not have a method with the name 'split'" while using $OrdnerAccess.Split("`n")